# python read_csv pandas parse column with format like 1990M01 to a montly date format

Tags: pandas, date, parsing

I have a CSV file like that

```
obs , yr30 , tbill3m , ret3m
1990M01 , 7.98 , 7.8 , 0.028205
1990M02 , 8.44 , 8.02 , 0.007481
1990M03 , 8.61 , 8.08 , -0.003713
```

I try to import it like that

```
data = read_csv('/mypath/mydata.csv', 
                  header=0,
                  index_col=0, 
                  parse_dates=['obs'])
```

However python does not undertand that it should be a yyyy-mm format, because the index is still using the 1990M01 like format

I look for the best practice to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

temp=u"""obs,yr30,tbill3m,ret3m
1990M01,7.98,7.8,0.028205
1990M02,8.44,8.02,0.007481
1990M03,8.61,8.08,-0.003713"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp),  
                 index_col=0)

print (df)
         yr30  tbill3m     ret3m
obs                             
1990M01  7.98     7.80  0.028205
1990M02  8.44     8.02  0.007481
1990M03  8.61     8.08 -0.003713
```

And then convert index to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%YM%m')
print (df)
            yr30  tbill3m     ret3m
obs                                
1990-01-01  7.98     7.80  0.028205
1990-02-01  8.44     8.02  0.007481
1990-03-01  8.61     8.08 -0.003713
```

Or then to month periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%YM%m').to_period('m')
print (df)
         yr30  tbill3m     ret3m
obs                             
1990-01  7.98     7.80  0.028205
1990-02  8.44     8.02  0.007481
1990-03  8.61     8.08 -0.003713
```

Comment: Thanks a lot love the df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%YM%m')
 solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `date_parser` option which accommodates non-standard date formats.

Using jezrael's data,

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp),
                 index_col=0, 
                 parse_dates=True, 
                 date_parser=lambda x:pd.datetime.strptime(x,'%YM%m'))
```

Comment: Thanks that sounds great as well. So are  to_datetime  and date_parser equals or is there for whatever reason one method which is better?

Comment: `date_parser` parses the date when reading the file. `pd.to_datetime` convert strings to datetime after the file got read.